# How do i make getting 4 pixels faster

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I have some code that is detecting pixel colors in range and pressing key for them

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
import pyautogui
import pydirectinput
import keyboard
import time

LeftPressed = False
MiddleLeftPressed = False
MiddleRightPressed = False
RightPressed = False

 region Info
 LeftPos = x 783, y 724 -> rgb = 255, 229, 15
 MiddleLeftPos = x 902, y 724 -> rgb = 255, 229, 15
 MiddleRightPos = x 1016, y 724 -> rgb = 255, 229, 15
 RightPos = x 1132, y 724 -> rgb = 255, 229, 15 endregion


while True:
    ss = ImageGrab.grab()
    r = ss.getpixel(xy=(783, 724))[0]
    if 225 < r <= 255:
        pydirectinput.keyDown('q')
        LeftPressed = True
    elif LeftPressed:
        pydirectinput.keyUp('q')
        LeftPressed = False
    else:
        LeftPressed = False

    r = ss.getpixel(xy=(902, 724))[0]
    if 225 < r <= 255:
        pydirectinput.keyDown('w')
        MiddleLeftPressed = True
    elif MiddleLeftPressed:
        pydirectinput.keyUp('w')
        MiddleLeftPressed = False
    else:
        MiddleLeftPressed = False

    r = ss.getpixel(xy=(1016, 724))[0]
    if 225 < r <= 255:
        pydirectinput.keyDown('o')
        MiddleRightPressed = True
    elif MiddleRightPressed:
        pydirectinput.keyUp('o')
        MiddleRightPressed = False
    else:
        MiddleRightPressed = False

    r = ss.getpixel(xy=(1132, 724))[0]
    if 225 < r <= 255:
        pydirectinput.keyDown('p')
        RightPressed = True
    elif RightPressed:
        pydirectinput.keyUp('p')
        RightPressed = False
    else:
        RightPressed = False
```

its that 4 times with 4 different locations and keys and everything works fine , but its just way to slow , when theres no pixel detected loop takes around 0.06 s, but when any pixel is detected and clicked(or key down thing), it takes loop from 0.2s to 0.4s, is there any way to improve this, tried to check profiler but got no idea how to use it in a while loop.
Edit: Cpu usage and ram are at like 0.2% - 2% for pycharm when code is running

Comment: Please post the shortest full .py source code which reproduces the problem.

Comment: Added full code in post

Comment: Python 3 gives me `IndentationError: unexpected indent` in line 12 (`region info`) for your code. Could you please post the correct code, without modifications?

Comment: region info is with # but couldnt post # on here because it makes like text weird

Comment: It's possible to post code with lines starting with `#`. Post the entire code between \`\`\` (3 backticks) lines. The syntax is called Markdown.

Answer (score 0):

- You can get rid of all the `else` clauses, since each of the variables must already be `False` when the `else` block is reached.
- If `r` is in the range 0..255, there's no need to compare it against 255; can just use: `225 < r`
- Rather than grabbing the whole screen, you can pass a rectangle to `ImageGrab.grab` (the smallest rectangle that contains the four points, you're using).

None of these feel like they would be a great speed-up, except perhaps the ImageGrab bbox.

As far as the profiler is concerned, you'd have to change the `while` loop to a `for _ in range(1000)` or similar so it runs for 3-7 minutes, then stops. You may also need to break the code into functions, I think most python profilers only profile whole functions rather than individual lines of code.

Comment: I tried to adding a bbox to imagegrab, but then the pixel positions are different and idk how to calculate new ones

Comment: To calculate the new coords, subtract the left and top coordinates of the box... If you want to check, you can also have PIL save the grabbed image to a file, then look at it in an image editor. However, subtracting the left and top coordinates should be correct.

Comment: Thanks added, bbox now its only like 300 pixels but its still super slow, ill try to make 4 different scripts each one has its own lane, maybe that will work better

Comment: 4 different scripts running in parallel made it way better

Comment: It can hit like 2 or 3 at the same time now and each one is faster by like 50 ms